# How to prevent HTTP GET for ASP.NET events? or How to check for Request.Type on all events?

Tags: c#, asp.net

With the help of fiddler, I did this "replay attack" with the following HTTP GET request

http://svr/Default.aspx?**__EVENTTARGET=LinkButton1**&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2snipg%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2snip

To my surprise, it works as long as there is valid viewstate and event validation.  The following stops GET on my click event, but...

```
protected void BtnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Request.RequestType == "GET") throw new HttpException(405, "GET not allowed for this.");
}
```

I have events *all* over my code. Is there a way to globally add this behavior to events that are normally postback events?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can yes. Attach to application's [PreRequestHandlerExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.prerequesthandlerexecute.aspx) event. Do it either as a separate `HttpModule` or in `Global.asax`.

In event hadler you can either check:

1. `_EVENTTARGET_` , `_VIEWSTATE_` are not part of `Request.QueryString` property (on each request)
2. on GET you can check that `Request.Form` is empty. Because asp.net only posts a form on POST actions.

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer has solved very well the issue for me.
As it only contains some suggestions, I would like to post my own answer with an example of implementation, hoping it will be helpful for somebody (the method name is the one to use for Global.asax, for a httpmodule feel free to adapt) :

```
    public void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The code below is intended to block incoming HTTP GET requests which contains in query string parameters intended to be used in webform POST
        if (Request.HttpMethod != "GET")
        {
            return; // Nothing to do
        }

        var hasPostParams = (Request.QueryString["__EVENTTARGET"] ??
                               Request.QueryString["__VIEWSTATE"] ??
                               Request.QueryString["__EVENTARGUMENT"] ?? 
                               Request.QueryString["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) != null;

        if (hasPostParams)
        {
           // TODO : log error (I suggest to also log HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl) and throw new exception
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never want to process GETs for this particular application on certain page types you can disable GET for the various pages in your application using IIS.  Under the Properties pane for the site or application click on Home Directory and then Configuration (assuming an application is configured) then click on the ASPX or other extension and you can limit the verbs in use for that extension.

Comment: Then how would you load the first page?  Browsers do the home page request with a GET.  The home page at least would have to be in a different virtual directory, the post would be cross virtual directory, all links would have to be converted to redirects, etc.  I haven't tried this but I'm not sure it would work.

Comment: Good point!  He could create a custom extension for the particular page, but it's obviously more convenient to use the picked answer.

Thanks for dogpiling on me Matt.  :-(  ;)